# Where are Windows 10 folder icons located?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Where I can find the folder icons for Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Music, Pictures and Videos? They are not inside `shell32.dll`.

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The icons you ask about are within the `C:\Windows\System32\imageres.dll` file.
[image]

## Supporting Resource

- [How to Change or Restore Downloads Folder Icon in Windows](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/116534-change-restore-downloads-folder-icon-windows.html)

  > The `C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll` and
  > `C:\Windows\System32\imageres.dll` files contain most of Windows
  > default icons.

Answer (score 8):

Those icons are NOT present inside `shell32.dll`.  *Desktop, Pictures, Downloads, etc.* and many more icons are inside `imageres.dll` which is `C:\Windows\System32\imageres.dll`

**Tip**: If you want to know where is the folder icon, you can do the following:

- Open the folder whose icon do you want to know.
- On the address bar of File Explorer, type `notepad desktop.ini`.
- Then check IconResource, IconFile, etc.